# Nav.Link to="/About" is not working in react-bootstrap? Nav.Link href="/About is working reloading the whole page

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

My desired outcome is to have navigation without relodaing the whole page.

```
<Nav.Link  to="/About">About</Nav.Link> is not working.
<Nav.Link  href="/About">About</Nav.Link> is working but reloading the whole page.
```

Nav.Link is imported from react-bootstrap.

What is the problem here, and How can I Route to another page without reloding  the whole page by react-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the double quote on your first Link. Try this:

`<Nav.Link to="/About">About</Nav.Link>`

Also, you need a router for this to work. Something like:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/about'>
      <About />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/users'>
      <Users />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/'>
      <Home />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: I have included <Router> in App.js file. Navigation is a different componet where I am trying to build a Navbar.

Comment: It doesn't matter, just be sure to wrap your navbar with your <Router>. something like <Router></yourNavbar /></switch><Route to="/About">...</Route></switch></Router>

Comment: The <switch> with its routes as children represent the area where your routed component will be displayed. The <Router> must Wrap your whole application

Comment: I have done it in App.js file. Should I do it again in Navigation.js file?

Comment: Problem solved! My Navigation component was outside of the <Router> in App.js file! Thanks.

Comment: As expected, glad I could help :)